# jQuery error in visibility despite functioning function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the problem that with my jQuery code, despite the working code, the error message:

> script.js: 28 Uncaught TypeError: $ (...). Css (...) is not a function

occurs. It was supposed to work anyway, but since I don't want any unnecessary error codes in my code, I ask if anyone has a solution to this error?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bgh-tooltipin1").hover(function () {
        $("#bgh-tooltipout1").css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function () {
        $("#bgh-tooltipout1").css('visibility','hidden')()
    });
});
```

Comment: Formatting your code properly does not only help readability, it makes spotting typos and syntax errors so much easier ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding unnecessary parenthesis at the end:

`$("#bgh-tooltipout1").css('visibility','hidden')**()**`

The last parenthesis would be fine if `.css('visibility','hidden')` returned a function, but instead, it returns a jQuery object representing the "#bgh-tooltipout1" element

This is the correct version:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#bgh-tooltipin1").hover(function () {
  $("#bgh-tooltipout1").css('visibility', 'visible');
 }, function () {
  $("#bgh-tooltipout1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
 });
});
```

Comment: You are right, I deleted my answer. Was jump instinct XD